# Application_Error: how to save exception information?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, error-handling

I am using the following code to capture exceptions in the application, and save them in the Session object. The exception is then retrieved from Session in the error handler page to which the app automatically redirects:

```
    protected virtual void Application_Error(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            Exception ex = Server.GetLastError();
            Session["exception"] = ex;
        }
        catch { }
    }
```

I have one problem with this code:

`Session` is not available if a malformed path gets in: `"example.com/"foo"` - Exception is thrown when accessing it, and NULL is retrieved from Session object in the error page

**What is a better way to save exception information in the application and pass it to the error handler action?**

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to log exceptions then take a look at the [elmah](http://code.google.com/p/elmah/) project.

[Scott Hanselman has a good introduction](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ELMAHErrorLoggingModulesAndHandlersForASPNETAndMVCToo.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

If you can't use ELMAH for any reason,

http://www.genericerror.com/blog/2009/01/27/ASPNetMVCCustomErrorPages.aspx

Comment: Link is dead. Consider removing answer.